# Python compare char to hex

Tags: python, compare, hex

```
>>> var = 'g'  
>>> print hex(ord(var))  
0x67  
>>> print hex(ord(var)) == 0x67  
False
```

Why isn't this true in python 2.7?
What would be the best way to compare 'g' to the hex value 0x67?

Comment: Thanks for all the great replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hex` returns a string, which you are comparing to a number. Either do

```
ord(var) == 0x67
```

or

```
hex(ord(var)) == "0x67"
```

(the first one is less error-prone, as it's case insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex)

> `hex(x)`
>
> Convert an integer number (of any size) to a lowercase
>   hexadecimal string prefixed with `0x`

So `hex(ord(var)) == '0x67'`

It just `print` that removes quotes.

See

```
>>> var = 'g'
>>> hex(ord(var))
'0x67'
>>> hex(0x67)
'0x67'
>>> hex(ord(var)) == hex(0x67)
True
```

And of course `ord(g) == 0x67` because numbers are equal *despite* of representation, i.e 0x67 and 103 and 0147 are all the same number internally

Answer (score 0):

First see the type of `hex(ord(var))`:

```
>>> print type(hex(ord(var)))
<type 'str'>
```

Then see the type of `0x67`

```
>>> type(0x67)
<type 'int'>
```

You are comparing a `str` with an `int`. So, you should do:

```
hex(ord(var)) == '0x67'
```

Comment: Because this answer has been given.

Comment: What is the meaning of `Because this answer has been given`?

Comment: @user3100115 To me, its very harsh to down vote an answer, just because an answer is already been given. There is no rocket science anyone should know before answering this question so that I have to copy the answer from someone else. Really meaningless and disrespectful.

Comment: It is because of reaction like this that people don't explain why they downvoted a post.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the ord and compare it to 0x67

```
>>> ord('g') == 0x67
True
```

If you do this:

```
>>> 0x67
103
```

You are still getting the ascii code for that character.

Furthermore, based on your explicit example, if you are trying to cast that to an int to actually compare to 0x67, then you need to do it in base-16:

```
>>> int(hex(ord('g')), 16) == 0x67
True
```

False case:

```
>>> int(hex(ord('d')), 16) == 0x67
False
```